# How to create a distributed system that performs a task and come to a consensus of result?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing, distributed-system, consensus

For more context-

I have a system that performs some operation(verification of some truth based on a local copy of data). This system can't be centralized because of all the demerits of a centralized system like a trust issue, single point of failure etc.

How to build a distributed system that can perform a task and come to a consensus on the result based on voting or majority.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to implement the paxos protocol (or 2 phase commit). Before you go ahead and start implementing your own, try out an open source alternative. For example: http://libpaxos.sourceforge.net/